# "Daily Usage" Quota is a per-project limit?

Tags: gmail-api

I have a question about Gmail API limit.

About "Daily Usage" Quota of the URL below, Is this a per-project limit?
Is there a way to relax this limitation?
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota

We currently develop services using the Gmail API for multiple Bussiness companies.
There is concern that it will exceed when the assumed total number of users becomes large, and I am asking such a question.

Is it possible to create different project for each customer and avoid the limit?
In that case, do I have to apply "OAuth Developer Verification" for each project?
https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification

Answer (score 0):

Understanding the quotas can be a little hard.  The way i remember is if the name has user in it its a user quota

This one is project based.

> Daily Usage    1,000,000,000 quota units per day

This one is user based.

> Per User Rate Limit    250 quota units per user per second, moving average (allows short bursts)

Some quotas can be increased you should check the quota section of the google developers console.   under Enabled APIs and services click the api in question and go to the quotas tab in the new window.  if there is a pencil icon you can increase it.